# Vaadin grid single selection don't highlight in Svelte

Tags: css, vaadin, svelte, web-component, vaadin-grid

I'm using Vaadin Grid with Svelte to display a list of users. The Single Selection Mode works perfect but it doesn't change the background color of the item.

1. [Reproducible example on Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/852ddab2a50640d0b67d9976708b0089?version=3.49.0)

```html
<script>
    import '@vaadin/grid'
    
    const items = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Car'}]
    let selected_items = []
    
    function change_selection(event) {
    const item = event.detail.value
    console.log(item)
    selected_items = item ? [item] : []
    }
</script>


<vaadin-grid
  {items}
  selectedItems={selected_items}
  on:active-item-changed={change_selection}>
  <vaadin-grid-column path="name" header="Name"/>
</vaadin-grid>
```

Try to click on an user, you will see in the console that is selected but not highlighted (no UI changes).

2. [Expected behavior on Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid#single-selection-mode)

Try to click on an user, now the style changes.

**Note:** we are not having problems with other Vaadin components styles.

---

If you want to do some testing with my example on Svelte REPL don't forget to save and clean cache to avoid "vaadin-lumo-styles" has already been used with this registry.
[image]

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Comment: It seems like Svelte is setting the items array as an attribute instead of a property, you can see it in the inspector `selecteditems="[object Object]"`. I'm not familiar with Svelte, but I assume there's a way to set it as a property. It's also interesting that the camel case name in your code is all lower case in the inspector for some reason.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcusHellberg, it should work but your point gave me a simple workaround solution.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `selectedItems` outside the HTML attribute makes the style works properly (thanks to Marcus comment).

```html
<script>
    import '@vaadin/grid'
    
    const items = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Car'}]
    let grid
    
    function change_selection(event) {
      const item = event.detail.value
      grid.selectedItems = item ? [item] : []
    }
</script>


<vaadin-grid 
  bind:this={grid}
  {items}
  on:active-item-changed={change_selection}>
  <vaadin-grid-column path="name" header="Name"/>
</vaadin-grid>
```

I hope this help others, in any case we are not having problems with other Vaadin Web Componets styles inside Svelte.